# Properties of matrices

Tags: matrices

[image]

Have I got these properties of matrices correct?

Comment: Maybe retry C. Just multiply your result by AB.

Comment: five of your six answers (counting unchecked entries as answers) are correct. One is wrong.

Comment: $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers are correct, except that C is false. The right side is the inverse of $BA$, because
$$(A^{-1}B^{-1})(BA)=A^{-1}(B^{-1}B)A=A^{-1}IA=A^{-1}A=I.$$
But must the inverse of $AB$ be the inverse of $BA$? See if you can find an explicit counterexample.

Comment: Actually, if the entries of A,B are in a ring, we may only have 1-sided inverses, I think.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that if the entries of A,B are in some ring R, and AB=I , I think we cannot conclude that BA=I.

Comment: I think you're right if $R$ is non-commutative, but for any commutative ring $R$, the collection of invertible matrices, i.e. $$\operatorname{GL}_n(R)=\{A\in M_n(R)\mid \det(A)\in R^\times\},$$
is a group, so there are always two-sided inverses.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: So I cant distribute the $^{-1}$ across A & B....because that is what I did for A..I thought that was a valid operation. Why is my answer for A correct?

Comment: @John: Your answer for A is correct because
$$(ABA^{-1})^3=(ABA^{-1})(ABA^{-1})(ABA^{-1})=$$
$$AB(A^{-1}A)B(A^{-1}A)BA^{-1}=ABIBIBA^{-1}=AB^3A^{-1}$$
You can't distribute a ${}^{-1}$ in general for matrices, unlike the case for numbers (this is ultimately because matrix multiplication is not always commutative). I'm not sure how distributing a ${}^{-1}$ would have come up in problem A though.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain themselves?

Comment: sorry i meant distributing the 3